# Get item filtered by specific tag and custom field

Tags: podio

I would like to get an item filtered by a specific **tag** AND order by a **custom date field** (extern ID is 'date')

I've tried multiple way according to the doc, such as PodioItem::Filter() with an array for the tag and a simple string too, but I didn't get expected result.

I know we can filter by tags and order by specific field ID, but I don't know how to do it.

Explaination from doc:

```
tags: Filter by the tags on the item
{field_id}: The id of the field to sort by, which can be fields of type "state", "text", "location", "money", "number", "calculation", "progress", "duration", "app", "date", "contact", "category" and "question".
```

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very bottom of this page http://podio.github.io/podio-php/items/ you can see how to do date filters. You can combine that with tags like so:

```
$items = PodioItem::filter($app_id, array(
  'filters' => array(
    $external_id_of_date_field => array(
      "from" => "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
      "to" => "2014-07-31 23:59:59"
    ),
    'tags' => array('tag1')
  ),
));
```